# Is there a way to skip the ENTER newline character when using multiple scanf statements?

Tags: c, scanf

Take the snippet below:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    printf("%d%c",a,c);
    return 0;
}
```

And lets say your inputs are 5 and a. The out put of the `printf` statement will be 5 followed by a newline, rather than the 'a'. I know this is because the `scanf` function treats the ENTER as a character, and that 'a' is really the third item in the queue, but is there a way to skip the ENTER without resorting to using an additional `scanf` statement?

Comment: Ditto. And read the docs about functions you are using. They have everything.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/1275169 Better yet, avoid scanf and use fgets or similar functions.

Comment: Thank you. I also noticed my question was a duplicate.